# Why are level ERROR not added to the errors file?

Tags: node.js, log4js-node

I use [log4js](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node) and want to write error logs to a separate file. But all error levels are recorded for some reason only in the access file. And because of this, the errors file is empty. How to fix it?

log4js.json:

```
{
    "appenders": {
      "access": {
        "type": "dateFile",
        "filename": "logs/access.log",
        "pattern": "-yyyy-MM-dd", 
        "category": "http"
      },
      "app": {
        "type": "file",
        "filename": "logs/project.log",
        "maxLogSize": 10485760,
        "numBackups": 3
      },
      "errorFile": {
        "type": "file",
        "filename": "logs/errors.log"
      },
      "errors": {
        "type": "logLevelFilter",
        "level": "ERROR",
        "appender": "errorFile"
      }
    },
    "categories": {
      "default": { "appenders": [ "app", "errors" ], "level": "DEBUG" },
      "http": { "appenders": [ "access"], "level": "DEBUG" }
    }
}
```